# How do I show the changes which have been staged?

Tags: git, diff, dvcs, git-diff, git-stage

I staged a few changes to be committed. How do I see the diffs of all files which are staged for the next commit? Is there a handy one-liner for this?

[`git status`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) only shows names of files which are staged, but I want to see the actual diffs.

The [`git-diff(1)`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) man page says:

> git diff [--options] [--] […]
>
> This form is to view the changes you made relative to the index (staging area for the next commit). In other words, the differences are what you *could* tell git to further add to the index but you still haven't. You can stage these changes by using git-add(1).

Comment: `git status -v` works too. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29116219/6309)

Comment: @VonC I always use this, but piped to `less`, as in: `git status -v | less` – manageable chunks :)

Comment: How can I grep `git diff --cached` for a string and return a list of the file names where a diff mentioned that string? Ah, I found the answer: `git diff --cached -G "your_search_string" | grep 'diff --git' | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d/ -f2-`

Answer (score 3147, accepted):

It should just be:

```
git diff --cached
```

`--cached` means show the changes in the cache/index (i.e. staged changes) against the current `HEAD`. `--staged` is a synonym for `--cached`.

`--staged` and `--cached` does not point to `HEAD`, just difference with respect to `HEAD`. If you cherry pick what to commit using `git add --patch` (or `git add -p`), `--staged` will return what is staged.

Comment: If you want the file names only, do the following `git diff --name-only --cached` per post at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4525025/255187

Comment: Use this with `git difftool --staged` rather than `git diff --staged` to launch the default visual diff tool on each file.  `difftool` can be substituted for `diff` with any other arguments as well.

Comment: And you can use `git difftool --staged -d` to diff the two directories in a visual tool rather than one file at a time.

Comment: since this one is marked as answer and showing first it should include git diff at the top, then git [[others]], just my 2 cents

Comment: And to view the changes in a single staged file, following will work:
`git diff --cached -- <stagedfile>`

Comment: is there a simplified one?

Answer (score 1758):

A simple graphic makes this clearer:

[image: Simple Git diffs]

**git diff**

Shows the changes between the working directory and the index. This shows what has been changed, but is not staged for a commit.

**git diff --cached**

Shows the changes between the index and the HEAD (which is the last commit on this branch). This shows what has been added to the index and staged for a commit.

**git diff HEAD**

Shows all the changes between the working directory and HEAD (which includes changes in the index). This shows all the changes since the last commit, whether or not they have been staged for commit or not.

**Also**:

There is a bit more detail on [365Git.](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/474079664/whats-the-difference-part-1)

Comment: This is naive, I'm afraid (as is usually the case with any git explanation). If you have local modifications to `foo.c` and do not perform `git add foo.c`, then `foo.c` is *not in the index*; it is not staged for commit. If `git diff foo.c` naively compared to the working `foo.c` to the index, then it would have to show a giant diff between an empty/nonexistent file and the entire contents of `foo.c`.  So in fact, when a file does not exist in the index, `git diff` falls back, for that file, on using the `HEAD` copy.

Comment: @Kaz strictly speaking, the index is **not** a blank slate. It's a virtual copy of the `HEAD` on which the staged changes are applied. Remember that Git works by saving changes, not by saving entire files. When you stage a file, it's only storing the changes made. If the index is blank like you imply, it wouldn't know how to save the changes in the index, and would have to save the entire file as "newly added" - which is wrong.

Comment: @Kaz Both the index and the `HEAD` will have the unchanged version of the `foo.c` file (they are not physical copies, but just logical copies to you and me. To Git they are just the same data stream that every commit that ever involved that file refers to). So when you do `git diff` on the *fully* unstaged `foo.c` it's not really falling back to `HEAD` it's actually doing the diff with the Index (which happens to contain the exact same version of the file as `HEAD` does). So the graphic is correct.

Comment: Hello, I would like to know what it means "**index**" in this context? Thanks!

Comment: @Gab When you change a file it is not automatically going to be in the next commit. You have to do a `git add` operation to do this. That's what the index is. The changes that have been made that will be committed to the repository on the next commit.

Comment: @Abizern So the index is the staged changes?

Comment: So how do these options compare to `git status -v`?

Comment: @TomRussell `git status -v` is equivalent to `git diff --cached` (plus `git status` of course)

Comment: @Gab是好人 More specifically, the index contains all tracked files, including the staged changes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47543410

Answer (score 72):

Note that `git status -v` *also* shows the staged changes!
(meaning you need to have staged -- `git add` -- some changes. No staged changes, no diff with `git status -v`.
It does that since [Git 1.2.0, February 2006](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf7bb589af739563c90dc32b4901bea73aaaa9d0))

In its long form (default), [`git status`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) has an undocumented "verbose" option which actually display the diff between HEAD and index.

And it is about to become even more complete: see "[Show both staged & working tree in git diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29116346/6309)" (git 2.3.4+, Q2 2015):

```
git status -v -v
```

Comment: The last line should be `git diff HEAD`

Comment: @artur why? The point of the answer is to mention that `git status -vv` also includes what `git diff HEAD` does.

Comment: Does not work on `git version 1.8.3.1`. I know it's old, but if possible, note when this flag was introduced.

Comment: @onebree 1.8.3.1 is June 2013, old indeed. But `git status -v` is older (https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf7bb589af739563c90dc32b4901bea73aaaa9d0, git 1.2.0, February 2006!). Note that it displays the diff between the **index** and `HEAD`: if you have added anything to the index (no `git add`), then `git status -v` would not display any diff. `git status -v -v` is more recent (Git 2.3.4, March 2015)

Comment: @VonC that was my mistake... I did `git diff -v`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have `git diff` configured to use a GUI for comparison, but often times I just want a console printout of changes. This is exactly that.

Answer (score 57):

If you'd be interested in a visual side-by-side view, the [diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/) visual diff tool can do that. It will even show three panes if some but not all changes are staged. In the case of conflicts, there will even be four panes.

[image: Screenshot of diffuse with staged and unstaged edits]

Invoke it with

```
diffuse -m
```

in your Git working copy.

If you ask me, the best visual differ I've seen for a decade. Also, it is not specific to Git: It interoperates with a plethora of other VCS, including SVN, Mercurial, Bazaar, ...

See also: [Show both staged & working tree in git diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13057457/946850)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a nice tool. I've found Meld to be the best visual diff tool for Linux so far, but I missed being able to diff text from the clipboard -- Meld requires files for input. Diffuse allows this, as well as manual realignment. Will try it out for a while.

Comment: Broken link to diffuse.sourceforge.net, use http://sourceforge.net/projects/diffuse/ for now.

Comment: `brew install diffuse` works on OS X. Doesn't show 3 panes if both unstaged and staged changes - did you mean changes not yet in the index?

Comment: Which version of diffuse do you have? Yes -- if you add a file and then modify it locally, it should show three panes.

Comment: You could also setup **diffuse** as your default **difftool** and use that built-in mechanism/tool/alias to launch it.  See my answer here: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/45684512/6501141>

Answer (score 47):

For Staging Area vs Repository(last commit) comparison use

```
$ git diff --staged
```

The  command compares your staged(`$ git add fileName`) changes to your last commit. If you want to see what you’ve staged that will go into your next commit, you can use git diff --staged. This command compares your staged changes to your last commit.

For Working vs Staging comparison use

```
$ git diff
```

The command compares what is in your working directory with what is in your staging area. It’s important to note that git diff by itself doesn’t show all changes made since your last commit — only changes that are still unstaged. If you’ve staged all of your changes(`$ git add fileName`), git diff will give you no output.

Also, if you stage a file(`$ git add fileName`) and then edit it, you can use git diff to see the changes in the file that are staged and the changes that are unstaged.

Comment: _"For Working vs Repository comparison use `$ git diff`"_. I'm pretty sure `git diff` compares between Working vs Staging. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1587952

Answer (score 36):

## USING A VISUAL DIFF TOOL

### The Default Answer (at the command line)

The top answers here correctly show how to view the cached/staged changes in the `Index`:

```
$ git diff --cached
```

or `$ git diff --staged` which is an alias.

---

### Launching the Visual Diff Tool Instead

The default answer will spit out the diff changes at the git bash (i.e. on the command line or in the console). For those who prefer a visual representation of the staged file differences, there is a script available within git which launches a visual diff tool for each file viewed rather than showing them on the command line, called `difftool`:

```
$ git difftool --staged
```

This will do the same this as `git diff --staged`, except any time the diff tool is run (i.e. every time a file is processed by diff), it will launch the default visual diff tool (in my environment, this is **VS Code**, using the `code` executable).

After the tool launches, the git diff script will pause until your visual diff tool is closed.  Therefore, you will need to close each file in order to see the next one.

---

### You Can Always Use `difftool` in place of `diff` in git commands

For all your visual diff needs, `git difftool` will work in place of any `git diff` command, including all options.

For example, to have the visual diff tool launch without asking whether to do it for each file, add the `-y` option (I think usually you'll want this!!):

```
$ git difftool -y --staged
```

In this case it will pull up each file in the visual diff tool, one at a time, bringing up the next one after the tool is closed.

Or to look at the diff of a particular file that is staged in the `Index`:

```
$ git difftool -y --staged <<relative path/filename>>
```

For all the options, see the man page:

```
$ git difftool --help
```

---

### Setting up Visual Git Tool

To use a visual git tool other than the default, use the `-t <tool>` option:

```
$ git difftool -t <tool> <<other args>>
```

Or, see the difftool man page for how to configure git to use a different default visual diff tool.

---

### Example `.gitconfig` entries for vscode as diff/merge tool

Part of setting up a difftool involves changing the `.gitconfig` file, either through git commands that change it behind the scenes, or editing it directly.

You can find your `.gitconfig` in your home directory,such as `~` in Unix or normally `c:\users\<username>` on Windows).

Or, you can open the user `.gitconfig` in your default Git editor with `git config -e --global`.

Here are example entries in my global user `.gitconfig` for VS Code as both diff tool and merge tool:

```ini
[diff]
    tool = vscode
    guitool = vscode
[merge]
    tool = vscode
    guitool = vscode
[mergetool]
    prompt = true
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    path = c:/apps/vscode/code.exe
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait \"$MERGED\"
    path = c:/apps/vscode/code.exe
```

Answer (score 29):

You can use this command.

```
git diff --cached --name-only
```

The `--cached` option of `git diff` means to get staged files, and the `--name-only` option means to get only names of the files.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Not sure why I would want this, with the `--name-only` option I might as well use the regular `git status`

Answer (score 21):

From version 1.7 and later it should be:

```
git diff --staged
```

Answer (score 10):

If your intentions are to push-target a remote repo branch and your first pass at a commit change log were incomplete, you can correct the commit statement before pushing like this.

## Locally

... make some changes ...

```
git diff # look at unstaged changes

git commit -am"partial description of changes"
```

... recall more changes unmentioned in commit ...

## git diff origin/master # look at staged but not pushed changes

... amend staged commit statement ...

```
git commit --amend -m"i missed mentioning these changes ...."

git push
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have more than one file with staged changes, it may more practical to use `git add -i`, then select `6: diff`, and finally pick the file(s) you are interested in.

Answer (score 9):

To see the differences for a specific stage file (or files) you can use

```
git diff --staged -- <path>...
```

For example,

```
git diff --staged -- app/models/user.rb
```

Answer (score 8):

By default **git diff** is used to show the changes which is not added to the list of git updated files. But if you want to show the changes which is added or stagged then you need to provide extra options that will let git know that you are interested in stagged or added files **diff** .

```
$ git diff          # Default Use
$ git diff --cached # Can be used to show difference after adding the files 
$ git diff --staged # Same as 'git diff --cached' mostly used with latest version of git
```

**Example**

```
$ git diff 
diff --git a/x/y/z.js  b/x/y/z.js index 98fc22b..0359d84 100644
--- a/x/y/z.js 
+++ b/x/y/z.js @@ -43,7 +43,7 @@ var a = function (tooltip) {

-        if (a)
+        if (typeof a !== 'undefined')
             res = 1;
         else
             res = 2;

$ git add x/y/z.js
$ git diff
$
```

Once you added the files , you can't use default of 'git diff' .You have to do like this:-

```
$ git diff --cached
diff --git a/x/y/z.js  b/x/y/z.js index 98fc22b..0359d84 100644
    --- a/x/y/z.js 
    +++ b/x/y/z.js @@ -43,7 +43,7 @@ var a = function (tooltip) {

    -        if (a)
    +        if (typeof a !== 'undefined')
                 res = 1;
             else
                 res = 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

`git gui` and `git-cola` are graphical utilities that let you view and manipulate the index.  Both include simple visual diffs for staged files, and `git-cola` can also launch a more sophisticated side-by-side visual diff tool.

See my closely related answer at [How to remove a file from the index in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32930362/86967), and also this official catalog of [Git - GUI Clients](https://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux).

Answer (score 1):

The `--cached` didn't work for me, ... where, inspired by `git log`

`git diff origin/<branch>..<branch>` did.

Answer (score 1):

Another tool that makes this easy is Magit mode in Emacs.  Its default view lists both staged and unstaged changes.  It acts like `git add -p` on steroids, because you can easily stage or unstage hunks (or even single lines of code) with editor commands.  It's important to know the standard git porcelain, but I rarely use `git diff --cached` anymore.

https://magit.vc/

Answer (score 0):

Think about the `gitk` tool also , provided with git and very useful to see the changes