# How do I see changes in the git index?

Tags: git

Say I do

```
git add foo.txt
```

Now, foo's changes are in the index (I'm assuming git was already tracking that file). Now, when I do git diff, I can't see the changes in foo by doing

```
git diff
```

Are there some extra things that `git diff` wants before it shows me those changes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I show the changes which have been staged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587846/how-do-i-show-the-changes-which-have-been-staged)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

- To show unstaged changes only:

```
git diff
```

- To show the staged/cached changes only:

```
git diff --cached
```

- To show both cached and uncached changes, compare the whole working tree to the named commit (HEAD):

```
git diff HEAD
```

Comment: ooh. Thanks! Why so many words for 1 concept! Let me see if I got this straight: staged (or cached) changes = changes that live in the index.

Comment: I came here looking for a way to see both the cached and uncached changes together, so +1 for mentioning `git diff HEAD`.