# Git Index has files without using `add`

Tags: git, tree, blob, restore, manpage

The `git` index allows us to specify the files that go into a new `tree` object - such a `tree` object is what any newly created `commit` object will point to.

I'm aware that using `git add <filename>` puts a file into the index so that a tree can be generated.

However, the index seems to store files even before they have been added to the index. After running the following command, even a "clean" directory will display all the same files as the commit pointed to by `HEAD`.

```
git ls-files --stage
```

(I assume that this displays the files in the `index` because `stage` [is synonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3516845/7102572) with `index`)

Why would `git` store "un-added" files in the index? Aren't these files available by looking at `HEAD`? This seems redundant.

---

The distinction between HEAD, index, and working tree gets even murkier when reading certain `man` pages. For example, this is from `man git-restore`.

> By default, if --staged is given, the contents are restored from HEAD, otherwise from the index

- I would think that if `b.txt` is edited but not added to the index (i.e. `git status` shows red letters), then the version of `b.txt` in the `index` is the same as in `HEAD`. However, `git restore --staged -- b.txt` does nothing whereas `git restore -- b.txt` restores the working tree to the version in the `HEAD` commit.
- If `stage` [is synonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3516845/7102572) with `index` then why would `--staged` refer to `HEAD` in this `man` page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `git ls-files --stage` to check your staged files, use `git status`.

---

When a human talks to another human about git, she/he generally uses "the index" to refer to the *changes you have staged* in your repo.

But from the point of view git internals: "the index" is actually *the content of the current HEAD commit* plus the changes you have staged.

To give a simple illustration: when you run `git diff --cached`, which compares *the index* with the current HEAD commit, files that haven't been modified are not reported as "missing" from the index.

`git ls-files --stage` just reports the content of the index (the git internal one). There are some specific cases when one may be interested in that information, but generally users are looking for `git status`.

---

Regarding `git restore`: I think there is a confusion between the `--staged` option for `git restore` and the `--cached` option for `git diff`.

([edit] I will also say that it is pretty misleading, on the git team part, to have a command which happily combines `-s`,`-S`,`--source` and `--staged`, and I also had a few headaches before I figured out what was what with that command. The use cases make sense though, imho.)

Note that the meaning of [`--staged` for `git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#Documentation/git-restore.txt--W) is very different : it specifies *where you want to write your files*, as in "in git storage, in the index" versus "on disk, in the worktree" (my "versus" is also misleading: you can actually ask for both with `git restore -SW`).

quoting the doc:

> -W, --worktree
> -S, --staged
>
> Specify the restore location. If neither option is specified, by default the working tree is restored. Specifying --staged will only restore the index. Specifying both restores both.

The documentation you quote is the one for [`-s|--source`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#Documentation/git-restore.txt--slttreegt) : if `-S|--staged` is specified, then the *default value for `--source`* is not the same.

So : if a file `b.txt` has no staged modifications, this means that the index content for that file is the same as HEAD's content, and, as you correctly observed, `git restore --staged -- b.txt` is a no-op.

The uses of `--staged` are the other cases:

- `git restore --staged -- b.txt` would *unstage staged changes* if there were any
- `git restore -s that/other/commit --staged -- b.txt` will put in the index the content of `b.txt` coming from `that/other/commit`, without changing the worktree
- etc ...

Comment: *joke* for added clarity, please refer to [the git manpage generator](https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/) */joke*

Comment: The distinction between reading from and writing to in `restore` is not worded well in the docs. Then, `index` is thrown into the mix to make it more confusing when the `index` is really identical to `HEAD` in most cases. They should have a `--dest=` option as a counterpart to `--source=`.

Comment: It still seems redundant to me that the index stores references to un-added files when these files are always going to be identical to those pointed to by the HEAD commit.