# How to make git status show only staged files

Tags: git, git-status

I would like to get a list of only the staged filenames. I can't find the equivalent flag for `--name-only` for the `git status` command. What is a good alternative?

The file list will be piped to `php -l` (PHP lint syntax checker).

**Solution: the complete command**

```
git diff --name-only --cached | xargs -l php -l
```

Comment: If you're running that command manually, it sounds like you might want to put it into a pre-commit hook. http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html

Comment: I think this is a better answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10018751/14454560

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Use `git diff --name-only` (with `--cached` to get the staged files)

Comment: Instead of `--name-only` you can use `--name-status` that also displays if the file was modified, added or deleted.

Answer (score 27):

The accepted answer won't let you know **what kind of changes** were there.

Yes, If you are not syntax checker but an ordinary person with a repository full of unstaged files, and you still want to know what will happen to staged files - there is another command:

```
git status --short | grep '^[MARCD]'
```

which leads to something like:

```
M  dir/modified_file
A  dir/new_file
R  dir/renamed -> dir/renamed_to
C  dir/copied_file
D  dir/deleted_file
```

Obviously, this files were staged, and after `git commit`:
`deleted_file` will be deleted,
`new_file` will be added,
`renamed_file` will become a `renamed_to`.

Here is an explanation of short-format output: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format

Comment: 1. in my version (2.25.0.windows.1) there's a space **before** "M" and "D". 2. There's also another state - "??" which I'm not sure how to interpret.

Comment: @itsho the space indicates that it is not staged. This answer is correct because it matches on the first character in the line. If the first char is set then it's a staged file. If it's a space it's ignored.

Comment: This is genius! - there should be a git flag for similar thing

Answer (score 10):

Inspired by [@coffman21](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50722236/618099)'s answer I have setup the following alias in my `.zshrc`

```sh
alias gst="git status"
alias gst-staged="git status --short | grep '^\w.'"
alias gst-unstaged="git status  --short | grep '^\W.'"
alias gst-unstaged-tracked="git status  --short | grep '^\s.'"
alias gst-untracked="git status --short | grep '^??'"
```

or

```sh
alias gst="git status"
alias staged="git status --short | grep '^\w.'"
alias unstaged="git status  --short | grep '^\W.'"
alias unstaged-tracked="git status  --short | grep '^\s.'"
alias untracked="git status --short | grep '^??'"
```

It might be of use to anyone else. So adding it to the stack of answers.

Comment: for consistent coloring you can add a `.` in grep, to color both 2 initial chars, like: `grep '^\w.'`, `grep '^\W.'`, `grep '^\s.'`

Comment: no need on the last one, though; it already has two chars `??`

Comment: That has now been fixed. Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

to view staged files with code changes

```
git diff --staged
```

or using `--cached` which is  synonym for `--staged`

```
git diff --cached
```

or to view only file names  without code changes

```
git diff --staged --name-only
```

[git-diff manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Answer (score 3):

## Show only staged files

```
git status --porcelain --untracked-files=all | grep '^[A|M|D|R]'
```

- [`--porcelain`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status/en#Documentation/git-status.txt---porcelainltversiongt) for parsing-friendly output
- [`--untracked-files=all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status/en#Documentation/git-status.txt---untracked-filesltmodegt) show all "untracked" files. Shows the files that are staged for commit.
- `grep '^[A|M|D|R]'` filter the output for files that are

  - `^` Match from the start of a newline. The first character of a line indicates the status in the staging area, the second in the working tree.
  - `A` added
  - `M` modified
  - `D` deleted
  - `R` renamed

This was based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372281/can-git-ls-files-list-the-changed-files-in-the-cached#comment69946377_41372281)

Answer (score 2):

To view which files are staged ,

```
git ls-files
```

Comment: This seems to only show committed files in the current directory, not staged.

Answer (score 0):

from @velocity
`git diff --staged` is exactly what I wanted. If anyone is looking to make this into a shortcut like `git ds` in your bashrc please see this example:

```
git() {
    if [[ $@ == "ds" ]]; then
        command git diff --staged
    else
        command git "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Git has its own aliasing functionality -- you can add `[alias]` (newline) `ds = diff --staged` to `~/.gitconfig` instead of doing this bashrc method.