# Git: How to list all (staged) files attempting to be committed

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, unix

Wrote a bash script for the prepare-commit-msg git hook.  It lists all staged files that exist, but I only want the staged files that are attempting to be committed (i.e. Example of desired input/output at the bottom of the page).

My script's job is to prevent a commit from happening if the files attempting to be committed did not follow a certain commenting convention (i.e. think java docs). Not only this, but it edits and auto formats the comments to meet my commenting convention.  This is extremely important to note because I can't just grab the SHA-1 of the commit because this script needs to happen before that key is ever created.

This works perfectly when I execute `commit -a` (i.e. commit all files).  However, I run into problems when I want to just commit a few of my staged files.

Is there a way I can catch only the staged files that are attempting to be committed, not just every single staged file that exists?

For example, let's say my staged files were the following:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
file5.txt
```

When I execute `git commit file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`, I want to catch `file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` in my script...but not `file4.txt` and `file5.txt`.

Is there anyway to do this?

EDIT: Definitely not a duplicate.  The solution to the "duplicate" question is definitely not what I'm asking for.

Comment: Ah I think you got some git vocabolary wrong: The file status can be one or more of untracked, ignored, tracked, staged and up-to-date. Tracked files are just the files that are part of the repository, staged files are staged to the so-called `index` (see gitglossary(7)). When you do a commit with files, you do two operations at once: add and commit. The same is true for `git commit -a` for just all files git finds and that are not ignored.

Comment: With that your second sentence reads: It lists all tracked files, but I only want the staged files. And that's what my command does, with the grep.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Name of staged files from git status?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524998/name-of-staged-files-from-git-status)

Comment: @ikrabbe When I do a `git reset E` as in your example, and then a `git status`, it lists `E` under untracked files and then tells me to `use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed).  Am I severely misunderstanding something or did something get lost in translation? :(

Comment: @ikrabbe, so what if I ran 'git add' on files 1-5 in my project.  Then I decide to only do `git commit file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`.  Using your commands listed below, will I see ONLY files 1-3 listed or will I see files 4 and 5 as well since I used a git add on them, but did not necessarily pass them as arguments to git commit?  Will test when I get home.

Comment: @MrPickles, no you need to get used the way git works, that introduces a step more than other version control systems. What you do: `git commit FILES` is a way git allows, but never recommends as it leads away from what git does backstage and that's also the reason why you are misunderstood. When you ran `git add` and you then run `git commit FILES`, the previous `git add` (staged files, index) gets completely ignored and the `git commit FILES` introduces a new set of staged files (index). I will show you the whole story in a blog or so... Let's see what this platform can do.

Comment: @ikrabbe. I think I finally get it now. `git commit FILES` is redudant is you use `git add FILES`? That actually makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I think you get through to the point. But `git commit FILES` is not exactly redundant, but a combined operation `git add FILES; git commit`, while previous `git add FILES` (staged, index), are temporarily moved to the background. This background operation is the main problem in understanding that convenience command `git commit FILES`. If I would rule the world, I would remove that command syntax. The command adds no useful function, but confuses new git users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Git commit operation, status and control

Git introduces its own terminology. Some of these words have been used in a wrong way, I will describe the misunderstood concepts and the problematic commands that lead to the erroneous formulation.

Luckily git has a very strong, defined language, where each term has an exact meaning, some of them can be seen in `git help gitglossary`. To understand the concepts git uses, the `git help git` page is worth to be read 5-50 times together with the introductory pages that are linked from there.

*If you installed a git version without the documentation, slap your system administrator. I assume, that most people who actively read questions, answers and articles are there own administrators, so slap yourself, but not too hard ;) Of course the docs can be found on the net, but they are an integral part of a to-be-used git installation.*

Luckily git was initiated and its core was completely written by one of the most excellent minds of our days or at least, by one who uses strictest logic concepts, instead of applying killer tools, to write and control his software development: Linus Thorvalds.

That makes it possible to use the same terms with defined meanings, when we talk about git and operations in a git repository. I won't go to deep though, as some of the concepts are developed with quite advanced theoretical terms in computer science in mind.

### The git repository

There are two main types of git repositories, called `bare` and `non-bare`, or I sometimes say *checked-out* (`git help init`). In this article I just talk about non-bare repositories, where the **tracked** files of the repository live in the **working directory**

> from gitglossary(7):
>
> ```
>  working tree
>       The tree of actual checked out files. The working tree normally 
>       contains the contents of the HEAD commit’s tree, plus any local
>       changes that you have made but not yet committed.
> ```

*Note for the Noobs: `gitglossary(7)` means the manual page with the name "gitglossary" in section 7. With `man` this page can be reached with `man -s7 gitglossary`. With `git help gitglossary` exactly the same will show, with `git help --web gitglossary` you see a well formatted document in your browser, if your system is configured to remote call a html page into your browser session. With Windows, where there is no `man` you will always be directed into the browser. For git commands such as **add** the manual page is `man 1 git-add` or `git-add(1)`.*

### Tracked Files

We have seen here, that the term **tracked** means that the git repository knows and controls that file. The glossary does not come from the `gitglossary(7)`, but from `git-add(1)`, option

> ```
>   -u, --update
>         Update the index just where it already has an entry matching 
>         <pathspec>. This removes as well as modifies index entries to 
>         match the working tree, but adds no new files.
>
>       If no <pathspec> is given when -u option is used, all tracked 
>         files in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of 
>         Git used to limit the update to the current directory and
>         its subdirectories).
> ```

The command **git add --update** is one of the most important operations to understand the handling of in the working tree by git.

#### Here shows the problem

with `git commit file1.txt file2.txt file4.txt`, but lets first define some more terms.

### Staged Files or Index

The set of staged files build the `index` (see gitglossary(7) for `index`, but ignore the several merge levels or the *unmerged index*). For our purpose

> `The index is a stored version of your working tree.`

namely that stored version of your working tree that is prepared to be committed as one `commit` (again gitgloassary(7)

> `commit`
>       `As a noun: A single point in the Git history;

... "revision" or "version" are synonyms from other version control systems. As Git users we say "commit".

... to be continued (26.Friday) ...

Comment: Wow, you are awesome.  Thank you so much.  I look forward to your post's update on Friday.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ git status -s -uno
M  E
A  R
```

The file E is modified, the file R is staged(added).

An unstaged file has the action marker in the second column (after `git reset E`, to unstage the file E):

```
$ git status -s -uno
 M E
A  R
```

These can be dropped with `grep -v '^ '` for example.

Here is a complete proof in my test directory:

## Tracked Files

```
 ~/test/ed $ git ls-tree HEAD
100644 blob 96bf192a9be8d1cecc314f66bb1ef5961564e983    E
100644 blob 11470e37f3d22a2548ce5c85040a44c9581d7727    I
100644 blob 8f2f9e95d9b00595d1588ccef91495c06295f5fa    O
```

## Filesystem Files (all, as in `git commit -a`)

```
 ~/test/ed $ ls -l .
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 ingo ingo 140 25. Jun 05:48 E
-rw-r--r-- 1 ingo ingo 143 25. Jun 05:39 I
-rw-r--r-- 1 ingo ingo 106 25. Jun 05:29 O
-rw-r--r-- 1 ingo ingo 157 25. Jun 05:28 R
```

## Status of the working directory: Changes against HEAD and staged files

```
 ~/test/ed $ git status -s -uno
 M E
A  R
```

## The output without the modified files that are not yet or no more (git reset) in the index (aka. not staged or unstaged)

```
 ~/test/ed $ git status -s -uno|grep -v '^ '
A  R
```

## Staged filenames only, without the operation flag

```
 ~/test/ed $ git status -s -uno|grep -v '^ '|awk '{print $2}'
R
```

Comment: It looks like that only unstages the file (i.e. makes the file untracked).  The command I am looking for is solely working with the set of all staged files.  Then the user will commit only a few of those staged files.  I want all of those files attempting to be committed, but not the staged files are not attempting to be committed (see example in question).

Comment: @MrPickles No! There is a difference between unstaged and untracked. Untracked files aren't part of the git objects database. That's why I use `-uno` to drop untracked files. Staged files are the files, that are introduced by add/rm for a commit. The modified files that aren't stage have not been added for a commit. I can extend the example with some exact proof, if I'm idle in the evening or tomorrow. But maybe you want to experiment with these outputs on your test repository and edit the answer. That would be even better.

Comment: @ikrabbe use long options when available to present commands in answers. It is way more readable, easier to remember, and friendlier with who is not familiar with the commands.