# Prevent git from committing files not staged for commit

Tags: git

I have a folder in my repository that contains a large number of files. 
If I have made changes to 20 files, and need to commit these files (say something like this)

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    SWIFT/db/add_sub_2lh.tdf
        deleted:    SWIFT/db/add_sub_ape.tdf
        deleted:    SWIFT/db/add_sub_bmb.tdf
        deleted:    SWIFT/db/add_sub_kka.tdf
        deleted:    SWIFT/db/cmpr_e7g.tdf
        deleted:    SWIFT/db/mult_6ct.v
        deleted:    SWIFT/db/prev_cmp_swift.qmsg
        deleted:    SWIFT/db/swift.(0).cnf.cdb
        deleted:    SWIFT/db/swift.(10).cnf.cdb
        deleted:    SWIFT/db/swift.(10).cnf.hdb
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   SWIFT/altpll_50M.bsf
        modified:   SWIFT/altpll_50M.cmp
        modified:   SWIFT/altpll_50M.qip
        modified:   SWIFT/altpll_50M.v
        modified:   SWIFT/altpll_50M/altpll_50M_0002.v
        modified:   SWIFT/altpll_50M_sim/mentor/msim_setup.tcl
        modified:   SWIFT/altpll_50M_sim/synopsys/vcs/vcs_setup.sh
        modified:   SWIFT/altpll_50M_sim/synopsys/vcsmx/vcsmx_setup.sh
        modified:   SWIFT/greybox_tmp/cbx_args.txt
        modified:   SWIFT/output_files/swift.flow.rpt
```

What I want to do is only commit the files that are staged for commit. I do not want the "changes not staged for commit" to be committed.
However when I run

```
git commit .
```

I see that all my changes are included in the commit.

If I use the -m option,I need to provide the file names, and I am not too keen to do that as the file names are all different and there are instances in my workflow, where the files may be in various nested folders

**[EDIT]**

If I use just

```
git commit
```

It will includes all the files that I have staged for committing in all the folders in the repository. I wish to commit only the files I have staged for committiing in the present folder or matching some pattern that I can specify on the command line

Comment: When you say "in the present folder", do you mean excluding subdirectories, or do you just mean "in a given directory" (and its subdirectories)?

Comment: No it will include sub diectories.

Comment: @DavisHerring, I am not looking for a script that will help me achieve this. I was wondering if git had the option natively. Something along the lines of "Git - please commit all these changes in the following directories that I have staged for commit. Do not commit any unstaged changes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the number of files fits in a single command line (and that there are no wildcards in the file names, since `git commit` will consider them again),

```
git diff -z --cached --name-only SWIFT/greybox_tmp '*.cdb' |\
  xargs -0 git commit -m "..."
```

will commit the staged versions of all files in the directory `SWIFT/greybox_tmp` or whose names end in `.cdb`.  (The `--cached --name-only` is [due to Ben Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4525025/8586227).)

The pathspec syntax is [quite intricate](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddefpathspecapathspec) and can even cover the "this directory but not subdirectories" case with `. :\!*/*` or (in newer versions) `:^*/*`.  We do still have to do a bit of scripting because it doesn't support filtering by "differs between `HEAD` and index".

Comment: Okay. But will this includes all the files that I have staged for committing in all the folders in the repository. I wish to commit only the files I have staged for committiing in the present folder or matching some pattern that I can specify on the command line

Comment: @Prashant: You should edit your question, then; that’s rather less trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `.`

```
git commit
git commit -m "ABC."
```

[From the docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html):

```
git commit [args] [file]
```

In your command, `.` is interpreted to mean everything in the current directory, thus you are staging all the unstaged files before the commit.

Comment: Note that this answers the original question as asked, but the OP then edited the original question into a substantially more complicated case.

Answer (score 1):

> I wish to commit only the files I have staged for committing in the present folder or matching some pattern that I can specify on the command line

You would need to [`git stash push a/path`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#_options) in order to save your index and working tree: a [pathspec can used a pattern](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddefpathspecapathspec).

Once what you don't want to commit is stashed, what remains in the index will be committed with a simple `git commit`.

Finally, a git stash pop will restore your working tree and index state.