# View diff of staged changes in git

Tags: git, git-diff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I show the changes which have been staged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587846/how-do-i-show-the-changes-which-have-been-staged)

Is there a simple way to view the diff of only the **staged** changes I have pending in git?  I've staged several files but want to take one last look at what I'm committing before I push the button.  I have several other unstaged changes that I want to go in a separate commit, so unstaging, doing `git diff`, and then paging through to the file I want isn't all that desirable an option.

Example:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   foo.java
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   bar.java
#       modified:   baz.java
#       modified:   qux.java
```

I really just want to see what I changed in `foo.java` without having to unstage.

Comment: @miku +1, voted to close as well (and leaving it here because it's [best practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/duplicate-question-etiquette-to-delete-or-not-to-delete) apparently), surprised that didn't show up when posting

Comment: Soon, you will be able to see both changes (staged and unstaged) with `git status -v -v`: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29116346/6309.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

One more minute of Googling found the answer of course, answering my own question:

```
git diff --cached
```

Comment: git diff --staged is a synonim and is more mnemonic for this case