# Show both staged & working tree in git diff?

Tags: git, diff

If I run `git diff` I see the changes in my working tree, and if I run `git diff --staged` (alternatively `--cached`) then I see the changes that are staged (w/ `git add`) but is there a way with `git diff` to see all in one go?

Comment: Amazing graphic explaining the different types of `git diff`s here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587846/how-do-i-show-the-changes-which-have-been-staged/1587952#1587952

Comment: `git status -v -v` will soon shows just that (git 2.3.4+, Q2 2015). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29116346/6309).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Is there a way with git diff to see all in one go?

There is, with Git 2.4.0+ (April 2015).

See [commit 4055500](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40555000935147f56896e75b919b25f1f2d23aca) from [Michael J Gruber `mjg`](https://github.com/mjg):

> #### `commit`/`status`: show the index-worktree diff with `-v -v` (or `-vv`)
>
> `git commit` and `git status` in long format show the diff between HEAD
>   and the index when given `-v`. This allows previewing a commit to be made.
>
> They also list tracked files with unstaged changes, but without a diff.
>
> Introduce '`-v -v`' (or `-vv`) which shows the diff between the index and the
>   worktree **in addition** to the `HEAD` index diff. This allows a review of unstaged changes which might be missing from the commit.
>
> In the case of '`-v -v`' (or `-vv`), additional header lines
>
> ```
> Changes to be committed:
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> Changes not staged for commit:
> ```
>
> are inserted before the diffs, which are equal to those in the status part; the latter preceded by 50*`-` to make it stick out more.

In the OP's case, a simple **`git status -v -v`** (or `git status -vv`) will show both staged *and* unstaged diffs.

Comment: In case it's not obvious to anyone, you can also combine the flags:  `git status -vv`

Answer (score 93):

If you mean the changes between the working tree and your HEAD commit (i.e. both staged and unstaged changes together) this is just done with:

```
git diff HEAD
```

Comment: No, OP wants "to see al in one go".

Comment: @user946850: And `git diff HEAD` shows all the changes (staged and unstaged) in one invocation of `git diff`.

Comment: On second reading, perhaps you're right. Note that this already has been covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1587952/946850

Comment: But the title suggests otherwise... Let's hear what the OP says.

Comment: @user946850: that's not a duplicate, though, because it specifically asks for staged changes [only]. I'm sure there is a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: I didn't say it was an exact dupe, and I haven't found "the" exact dupe yet.

Comment: I promise I searched hard! Anyway, thanks for the answer, this does the trick.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it works just as well with `git difftool HEAD` 

Comment: It didn't show new added untracked file on my end  :-( But after I did 'git add newFile' it showed it @CB Bailey

Comment: From git version 1.8.5 onward, `HEAD` can be replaced with `@` in most situations, so you can run a shorter version of the command in the answer: `git diff @`.

Answer (score 4):

The [diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/) visual diff tool can do that: It will show three panes if some but not all changes are staged. In the case of conflicts, there will even be four panes.

[image: Screenshot of diffuse with staged and unstaged edits]

Invoke it with

```
diffuse -m
```

in your Git working copy.

If you ask me, the best visual differ I've seen for a decade.

Comment: Great tip and much appreciated, but not exactly an answer since I asked for the git command to do this. Marking the other one as the answer...