# Differences between the staged and unstaged versions of the same file, using difftool

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, difftool, git-stage

Is there a way of viewing the differences between the `staged` and `unstaged` versions of the same file?

For example:

```
Changes to be committed:

    modified:   conf/application.conf

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   conf/application.conf
```

This happens when I stage a change and then I modify the file again, without staging it.

`EDIT`

The `git status -vv` command is not good enough, because I need to use the `diff` / `difftool` command. That's because in practice there are too many changes in too many files, and scrolling through all of them is not efficient. But `diff` / `difftool` allows me to specify the file I am interested in.

Comment: It's the same file.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yes, that's the point. Git concentrates on the changes to a file, not the file itself. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837841/git-can-a-file-be-both-staged-and-unstaged-for-commit

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`git diff`   will show the difference between your workspace and the index.
(the index is where the staged files live)

This may not seem obvious because we usually use `git diff` to see the changes in the workspace vs what is checked in.  However, technically `git diff` shows workspace vs index,  and if you haven't added changes to the index, then the index matches what you checked out.

- to see workspace vs repo:  `git diff HEAD`
- to see index vs repos: `git diff --cached` (can also use --staged)
- to see workspace vs index:  `git diff`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the command `git status -vv` you will see the textual changes of the file.  See [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status).

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: Can you elaborate @DrKaoliN, maybe I misunderstood.  Running that command will show all the changes to `conf/application.conf` that have occurred since you staged it.  Is that not the same thing as showing the difference between the staged and upstaged version of `conf/application.conf`?

Comment: Well, that particular command does not help me because I need to use the `diff` or the `difftool` command, so that I can see those differences _just for the specified file_ i.e. I can type `git diff conf/application.conf` but typing `git status -vv conf/application.conf`, will still show me all the changes in the console. Because in practice I never have just one file modified, there are perhaps tens of files, with tens of modified lines of code, and scrolling for half a minute to find what I need is not efficient. But _technically_, your answer is correct, indeed.

Comment: I see, makes sense.  Thanks for the clarification @DrKaoliN.