# Show both worktree and index changes for a single path in git

Tags: git

I want to show the result of both `git diff <PATH>` and `git diff --staged <PATH>`. I know this answer ([Show both staged & working tree in git diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057457/show-both-staged-working-tree-in-git-diff)) says you can use `git status -vv`, but it doesn't accept a path argument so I can't do `git status -vv -- <PATH>`. Anyone know a way to show both worktree and index diffs for a single path?

I need this solution for a script so I don't mind having to run multiple commands to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume above that you mean `--cached` or `--staged`, not `--index`.)

The `git status` command literally just runs two diffs (easy, since it has `git diff` built into it: that's just two subroutine calls).  You can do the same: just run `git diff -- path` and `git diff --cached -- path`.

If you want to make your script more bulletproof, be aware that `git diff` is so-called *porcelain* and thus changes behavior based on user configurations.  To avoid this, use the plumbing commands that `git diff` and `git diff --index` will use:

```
git diff-files -p -- <path>
git diff-index --cached HEAD -p -- <path>
```

You must decide for yourself, based on intended usage, whether your script *should* obey user configurations (in which case, don't use the plumbing commands) or not (in which case, do use them).

Comment: Thank you for your very insightful answer @torek. And yes, I meant --staged, edited original question.