# What is the difference between git diff HEAD vs. git diff --staged?

Tags: git

What is the difference between `git diff HEAD` and `git diff --staged`? I tried both but both give the same output.

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587846/how-do-i-show-the-changes-which-have-been-staged

Comment: @Johnsyweb sorry; "exactly" same output

Comment: `--staged` is a synonym for `--cached`. The diagram in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587846/how-do-i-show-the-changes-which-have-been-staged explains the difference. Marked as a duplicate

Comment: Soon (Git 2.3.4+, Q2 2015), `git status -v -v` will show clearly the difference between the two diffs: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29116428/6309)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Suppose this output for `git status`:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   y
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   x
#
```

As you see, there is one file modified but not staged for commit, and a new file added that is ready to be committed.

`git diff --staged` will only show changes to files in the "staged" area.

`git diff HEAD` will show all changes to tracked files. If you have all changes staged for commit, then both commands will output the same.

Comment: Shouldn't it be untracked files at the place of tracked files ? Because when I do git status without adding a file, it shows the unstaged file as untracked file.

Comment: If it is a new file that you have not added previously, it will show as untracked and not appear in any `git diff` variant. If the file has been added and committed before, and you have made modifications to it, then it will show as 'not staged for commit'

Comment: Is there a way to `diff` changes between the staged version and the unstaged version of the same file?

Comment: @geremia `git diff --staged` does that, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós Oh, yes, as long as you specify the file, that will diff its staged vs. unstaged versions.

Answer (score 86):

- `git diff` View difference between Stage and Working Directory
- `git diff --staged` View difference between HEAD and Stage
- `git diff HEAD` View difference between HEAD and Working Directory

[image]
[img src](https://lafkblogs.wordpress.com/2015/12/08/why-git-diff-shows-nothing/)

- `HEAD` is a reference to the last commit in the currently checked-out branch.
- Staging area, stage and index all mean the same thing
- Unstaged changes exist in our **Working Directory**, but Git hasn’t recorded them into its version history yet.
- Staged changes are a lot like unstaged changes, except that they’ve been marked to be committed the next time you run git commit

Comment: Top graphic was helpful to me. Lower graphics not so much.

Comment: @NickWeavers I removed the graphics because they are pretty distracting, and do not add to the answer.

Comment: anyone have any idea what tool was used to create the top graphic?

Comment: @creativemateriel I think TikZ was used: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package

Comment: Is `maint` the name of branch?

Comment: @Premraj Is it also correct to say that git diff HEAD compares the HEAD to working directory, NOT including untracked files?

Answer (score 10):

You will be able to see more easily the difference between the two diff with the upcomming (Git 2.3.4+, Q2 2015) **`git status -v -v`**

See [commit 4055500](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40555000935147f56896e75b919b25f1f2d23aca) from [Michael J Gruber `mjg`](https://github.com/mjg), it does a good job explaining the difference between `git diff HEAD` and `git diff --staged`:

> #### `commit`/`status`: show the index-worktree diff with `-v -v`
>
> `git commit` and `git status` in long format show the diff between HEAD
>   and the index when given `-v`. This allows **previewing a commit to be made**.
>
> They also list tracked files with unstaged changes, but without a diff.
>
> Introduce '`-v -v`' which shows the diff between the index and the
>   worktree **in addition** to the `HEAD` index diff. This allows a **review of unstaged changes which might be missing from the commit**.
>
> In the case of '`-v -v`', additional header lines

```
Changes to be committed:
# and
Changes not staged for commit:
```

> are inserted before the diffs, which are equal to those in the status part; the latter preceded by 50*"`-`" to make it stick out more.

Answer (score 2):

Another edge case difference:  In a newly created git repo, where only `git init` has been run so far, `git diff HEAD` will result in a fatal error (ambiguous argument 'HEAD') while `git diff --staged` will produce no output.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get different output from the two diff commands if you are running them on an unsuccessful merge, i.e. unmerged paths.

I have not been able to find out why it behaves like this, but you could read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215651/why-doesnt-git-diff-show-anything-for-unmerged-paths)