# What is Git actually doing when I run git diff

Tags: git, git-diff

As a newcomer to Git, can somebody please explain in relatively simple terms what `git diff` actually does, without going into branching/merging etc?

From my experience I know the outcome of running it:
Any files in my working directory that are different to those in my repo will be returned by `git diff` AS LONG AS they have not been put in the staging index.

If all my changes have been put in the staging index, `git diff` will return nothing. To see my changes, I have to use `git diff --staged`.

Is there a simple way to some this up? I can't quite get my head around the caveat about the staging index.

Comment: You have very good explanations in the answers for the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587846/how-do-i-show-the-changes-which-have-been-staged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, `git diff` shows unstaged changes.

Technically it's a difference between working tree and index tree (which, when nothing is staged, is identical to HEAD's tree, i.e. last commit).

And 'tree' in git-speak is a snapshot of files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to read this book (freely available): http://git-scm.com/book

Answer (score 0):

You can read the [manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html). The "Description" part explains all the variations on `git diff`, `git diff --cached`, `git diff commit1 commit2`, etc...

I would suggedt using `git status` to have a clear picture of the state of your files.

You can then use `git diff HEAD -- <path/to/file>` to view the differences between a file in its current state and the last commited version.