# Git diff for added file

Tags: git, diff

Normally I use `git diff` to check the changes of uncommited files (not yet `git add`ed) with the last commited one.

But after doing `git add somefile` (but not yet `git commit`ed), how to check the diff of that file?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587846/how-do-i-show-the-changes-which-have-been-staged/1587877#1587877 . Seems to be a duplicate

Comment: yes it's duplicate.. (I didn't know if the correct term is `staged`) 
I have vote to close the question..

Comment: I think this question is easier to find if someone doesn't know the concept of staging area in Git.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can check

```
git diff --cached -- yourFile
```

That will diff between HEAd and the index.

[image: http://images.abizern.org.s3.amazonaws.com/365git/Feb11/Git%20Diff%202.png]

<sup>(from [365git.tumblr.com](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/3464927214/getting-a-diff-between-the-working-tree-and-other))</sup>

The `--` helps separating the command from the parameters

See more on the double hyphen syntax in "[Deleting a badly named git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309)".

Comment: you again ^_^ thank you sir!