# Git: Check programmatically if anything is staged

Tags: git

For a Git script I'm writing, I'd like to have a programmatic way to check whether there is anything at all staged. i.e. I want a positive result if anything at all is staged, and negative if nothing is staged.

Bonus points: A way to programmatically check whether there is anything new in the working tree that can be staged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I show the changes which have been staged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587846/how-do-i-show-the-changes-which-have-been-staged)

Comment: You can use various flags to `git diff` to test what's staged/can be staged.

Comment: Not *quite* a duplicate, since `--exit-code` isn't mentioned there, and is counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
git diff --cached --quiet
```

(or replace `--quiet` with `--exit-code` if you still want output)

Answer (score 6):

The short format output of the [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) command<sup>1</sup> gives an output that can be used in a programmatic way:

> ### [Short Format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format)
>
> In the short-format, the status of each path is shown as one of these forms
>
> ```
> XY PATH
> XY ORIG_PATH -> PATH
> ```
>
> where `ORIG_PATH` is where the renamed/copied contents came from. `ORIG_PATH` is only shown when the entry is renamed or copied. The `XY` is a two-letter status code.

Further down, [an older (more-quotable) version of the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status/2.21.0#_short_format)<sup>2</sup> says:

> For paths with merge conflicts, `X` and `Y` show the modification states of each side of the merge. For paths that do not have merge conflicts, `X` shows the status of the index, and `Y` shows the status of the work tree. For untracked paths, `XY` are `??`. Other status codes can be interpreted as follows:
>
> - **' '** = unmodified
> - **M** = modified
> - **T** = file type changed (regular file, symbolic link or submodule)<sup>2</sup>
> - **A** = added
> - **D** = deleted
> - **R** = renamed
> - **C** = copied (if config option `status.renames` is set to "copies")<sup>2</sup>
> - **U** = updated but unmerged
>
> Ignored files are not listed, unless `--ignored` option is in effect, in which case `XY` are `!!`.

The short format is obtained by using [`git status -s`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#Documentation/git-status.txt--s). This should give you all entries that have been staged so far:

```bash
git status -s | grep "^[MTADRCU]"
```

You can also add the `-c` flag to `grep` to count the lines instead of printing them.

**Bonus:** Anything new to the working tree that hasn't been staged yet (is still untracked) can be found with:

```bash
git status -s | grep "^??"
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> This text is also available as the helppage at `git status --help`.

<sup>2</sup> The [up-to-date documentation version](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format) is less succinct, owing to more explicit language around merge conflicts. I have marked codes that were added or modified in a Git version after the quoted version.</sub>

Comment: If you want a line per untracked file rather than the summarized view for new folders, tack on `--untracked-files=all`. You can also save a couple CPU cycles with `--no-ahead-behind` to skip checking for commits.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a practical example of [J.Baoby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40835502/241211). I run something like this in a loop over a set of repositories for a summary of uncommitted files in each.

```bash
function ordered_count() {
    # modified from https://superuser.com/a/529837/23156
    # echo "$data" | ordered_count -c foo -c bar
    awk -F' ?-c ' '
    BEGIN { split("'"$*"'", pattern) }
    { for (i = 2; pattern[i]; ++i) if (match($0, pattern[i])) ++count[i] }
    END { for (i = 2; pattern[i]; ++i) print count[i] }
    '
}

# The `$@` is so you can add extra args, e.g. `-- important/path`
gitstatus=$(git status --short --untracked-files=all --no-ahead-behind $@)

# Staged changes
mapfile -t staged_added_removed_changed < <(
    echo "$gitstatus" |
    ordered_count \
        -c "^[ACR][^AU]" \
        -c "^D[^AUD]" \
        -c "^[MR]" \
)

# Unstaged changes
mapfile -t unstaged_added_removed_changed_conflicted < <(
    echo "$gitstatus" |
    ordered_count \
        -c '^([ D]C| A|\\?\\?)' \
        -c "^[^UD]D" \
        -c "^.[MR]" \
        -c "^(.U|U.|AA|DD)" \
)

# Do stuff with the arrays
```