# How can I have 2 independent local Git branches off same remote branch

Tags: git, branch, git-worktree

I have a master branch and am working on 2 features which involve the same files. I want to have 2 local branches pointing to the same upstream master but have different changes. I don't want to commit changes locally so that IDE preserves the formatting like the border shades in
https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/idea/files/2018/10/k8sCompletion.png

I have been unable to use git checkout successfully because when I make changes in one and switch to other branch, the unstaged changes are visible on it too. The solution I have come up with is checking out my code in 2 repos because git worktree seems to require 2 different remote branches. However, this means hard disk inefficiency. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

I expect that when I switch between local branches, even the unstaged changes of one branch should not be visible in the other.

Comment: I don't get about why are you reluctant to commit ? what do you mean by  `so that IDE preserves the formatting` ?

Comment: See the link I added- IntelliJ provides a different border shading for new or modified lines- all this is lost once I do a git commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: your problem is actually pretty trivial, provided your Git is at least version 2.15: just use `git worktree add` correctly, creating two branches that use the same remote-tracking name as their upstream.

If not, your method of using two repositories is perhaps the best.  You may still be able to use `git worktree add` for versions between 2.5 and 2.15 as long as you avoid one major issue (which I'll get into below).

#### Long

> I expect that when I switch between local branches, even the unstaged changes of one branch should not be visible in the other.

This expectation is not supported by Git.

The real problem here is that there no such thing as "unstaged changes", and no such thing as "staged changes" either.  What you see as either is an illusion, created on the fly, because the illusion tends to be *more useful* to a human programmer.  What Git shows you as *changes* are computed on demand, by comparing two of three items: the *current commit*, the *index*, and the *work-tree*.  In reality, though, there are merely *files*, stored in the work-tree and in the index, that are impermanent and changeable; plus *commits*, stored in the repository, that are permanent—well, mostly permanent—and frozen for all time.  See my recent answer to [Why does output differ under git diff vs. git diff --staged?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53904756/1256452) for much more about this.

There are (potentially) many commits in the repository, but each repository comes with only one (1) work-tree + index pair.<sup>1</sup>  You can add more pairs of index-and-work-tree using `git worktree add`, which you have tried.  This should work well for your case, as long as your Git is at least version 2.15 (from Git 2.5 up through but not including Git 2.15, `git worktree add` has a potentially-serious bug, depending on precisely how you use it).

---

<sup>1</sup>A bare repository (created with `git clone --bare` or `git init --bare`) has one index and *no* work-tree, but it seems safe to assume that you are not working with a bare repository.

---

> ... git worktree seems to require 2 different remote branches

This is not the case.

What `git worktree add` does is add an index-and-work-tree pair.  The added work-tree is in a separate work-tree directory (the main work-tree directory lives right next to the main repository's `.git` directory; the `.git` directory contains *all* the indices along with all of the other auxiliary information Git needs).  The added work-tree comes with its own `HEAD` as well, but shares all the *branch names* and *remote-tracking names*.

The constraint that `git worktree add` imposes is that every work-tree must use a different branch name, or no branch name at all, for its `HEAD`.  To properly define how this works, we need a digression about `HEAD` and branch names.  I will get to this in just a moment, but first, let's

Note: there is no such thing as a *remote branch*.  Git does have a term that it calls *remote-tracking branch names*.  I now prefer to call these *remote-tracking names* as they lack one crucial property that branch names possess.  A *remote-tracking name* typically looks like `origin/master` or `origin/develop`: that is, a name that starts with `origin/`.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>You can define more than one remote, or change the default name of the one remote that you might already have to something other than `origin`.  For instance, you could add a second remote named `upstream`.  In this case, you might also have `upstream/master` and/or `upstream/develop`.  These are all valid shortened forms of remote-tracking names.

---

#### Commits, branch names, and HEAD

The unit of permanent storage in any Git repository is the commit.  Commits are, as you have seen by now, identified by a big, ugly, apparently-random (not at all random), unique-to-each-commit *hash ID* like `5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7`.  These things are not useful to humans and we generally only use them via cut-and-paste, or indirectly, but the hash IDs are the real names.  If you have `5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7` (a commit in the Git repository for Git), it's *always* that particular commit.  If you don't have it, you can get a copy of the Git repository for Git (or update your existing copy), and now you *do* have it, and it's *that* commit—and it is Git version 2.20.  (The name `v2.20.0` is the more human-oriented name for this commit, and is what we'd normally use.  Git stores a translation table of tag names to hash IDs, which is how `v2.20.0` comes to be the human-readable name for this commit.)

A commit contains a full, complete snapshot of *all of the files* that were in the index at the time someone instructed Git to make the commit.  However, it *also* contains some additional *metadata*—data *about* the commit, such as who made it, when, and why (user name, email address, time stamp, and log message).  In that same metadata section, Git stores the exact hash ID of the *previous* commit.  Git calls that previous commit the *parent* of the commit.

In this way, *every commit ever made* in a repository connects back to the earlier commits in that same repository.  This is the history in the repository: the string of commits, starting at the end, and working backwards.  In very simple cases, such as in a pretty new repository, we might just have a few commits in a very simple line like this:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Here, the uppercase letters stand in for the actual hash IDs (which, remember, are big, ugly, and apparently-random).  What we—and/or Git—will do is start at the *end*, at commit `C`, and work *backwards*.  Commit `C` stores the actual hash ID of commit its parent `B`, so that from `C` we can find `B`.  Meanwhile `B` stores the hash ID of parent `A`.  Since `A` is the very first commit, it has *no* parent, and that's how Git tells that we have reached the beginning of history: there's nowhere left to go.

The trick, though, is that we need to *find* commit `C`, whose hash ID is something apparently-random.  This is where *branch names* come in.  We pick a name like `master` and use it to store the actual hash ID of `C`:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

We mentioned earlier that commits, once made, can never change.  This means we don't really need to draw all the internal arrows: we know that a commit can't remember its children, because they don't exist when we make the commit, but a commit *can* remember its parent, because the parent does exist at that time.  Git will freeze the parent hash into the new commit forever.  So if we want to add a new commit to our string of three, `A-B-C`, we just do that:

```
A--B--C--D
```

In order to remember `D`'s hash ID, Git immediately writes the *new* commit's hash ID into the name `master`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

So *commits* are fixed for all time, but *branch names* move, all the time!

Now, suppose we add a new branch name, `develop`.  A branch name, in Git, *must* point to *exactly one commit*.  The one commit we'd like it to point to is probably the latest, `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- develop, master
```

Note that *both names point to the same commit*.  This is perfectly normal!  All four commits are on *both* branches.

Now let's add a new commit, and call it `E`:

```
A--B--C--D
          \
           E
```

Which of the two branch names should we have Git update?  This is where `HEAD` comes in.

Before we make `E`, we tell Git *which name to attach `HEAD` to*.  We do this with `git checkout`.  If we `git checkout master`, Git will attach `HEAD` to the name `master`.  If we `git checkout develop`, Git will attach `HEAD` to the name `develop`.  Let's do the latter before we make `E`, so that we start with:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- develop (HEAD), master
```

Now we'll make `E`, and Git will update the name to which `HEAD` is attached, i.e., `develop`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

This is, in short, how branches grow.  Git creates a new commit whose parent is the current commit, as found via the name `HEAD`, which is attached to some branch name.  After creating the new commit—which gives it a new, unique, big ugly hash ID—Git writes the new hash ID of the new commit into that same branch name, so that the branch name now points to the new commit.  The new commit continues to point back to the old commit.

#### Added work-trees require that you attach their HEADs to different branches

For reasons that will make sense in a moment, `git worktree add` requires that a newly added work-tree use a *different branch name* for that work-tree's `HEAD`.  That is, when we draw the commits and branch names and attach `HEAD` to some branch name, we're really attaching *this* work-tree's `HEAD`, as there is now more than one `HEAD`.

So now that we have two names, `master` and `develop`, we can make two different work-trees, using these two different branch names:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD)    # in work-tree M
          \
           E   <-- develop
```

vs:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           E   <-- develop (HEAD)  # in work-tree D
```

The contents of a work-tree, and its index, will in general start out matching those of its `HEAD` commit.  We'll modify some files in the work-tree, `git add` them to that work-tree's index, and `git commit` there, and update *that work-tree's `HEAD`*.  That's *why* these two need to use different branch names.  Watch what happens as we work inside work-tree M (for master).  We start out with:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD)    # in work-tree M
          \
           E   <-- develop
```

The index and work-tree match commit `D`.  We do some work, `git add`, and `git commit` to make a new commit.  The new commit's hash ID is new and unique; let's call it `F` here, and draw it in, updating the name `master`:

```
A--B--C--D--F   <-- master (HEAD)    # in work-tree M
          \
           E   <-- develop
```

Now let's navigate over to the other work-tree (D for develop, but that sounds a lot like commit `D`, so let's just stop naming it like this).  This has its own `HEAD` so the picture is:

```
A--B--C--D--F   <-- master
          \
           E   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Note that `master` has changed—the *branch names* are shared between all the work-trees—and new commit `F` has appeared, as the commits are also shared.  But `develop` still points to commit `E`, and our index and work-tree here, in this work-tree, match those of `E`.  Now we modify some files, `git add` to copy them back into the index, and `git commit` to make a new commit that we can call `G`:

```
A--B--C--D--F   <-- master
          \
           E--G   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Commit `G` will appear in the other work-tree, and the other work-tree's `develop` will identify commit `G`, but since the other work-tree has `master` / commit `F` checked-out, the other work-tree's index and work-tree will still match commit `F`.

#### The upstream setting of any branch name is something you control

When you create a *new* branch name, using either `git checkout -b` or `git branch`, *you* control:

- whether that new branch has any upstream setting, and
- if so, what name—`origin/whatever` is typical, but it can be *any* name—is stored in that setting.

It's very normal for your `master` to use `origin/master` as its upstream name, and for your `develop` to use `origin/develop` as its upstream name, but there are no constraints here at all.  You can have *all* your branches *share* `origin/master` as their upstream, for instance.  Or, you can have branches that have *no* upstream set.  See [Why do I have to "git push --set-upstream origin <branch>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37770467/1256452) for a discussion of upstream settings.

There is a magic default:

```
$ git checkout feature-xyz
```

will try to check out your existing `feature-xyz` branch.  If there *isn't* a `feature-xyz` branch, your Git will check all your remote-tracking names, to see if there is, for instance, an `origin/feature-xyz`.  If so, your Git will *create* your own `feature-xyz`, pointing to the *same commit* as `origin/feature-xyz`, and with `origin/feature-xyz` set as its upstream.  This is intended as a convenience.  If it's inconvenient, don't use it: use `-b` instead.

The `git worktree add` command shares this particular trick with `git checkout`: Both have a `-b` that creates a *new* branch (without doing this), and both default to trying to check out some *existing* branch.  So both will automatically create a new branch with an upstream set, for this particular case.

#### Detached HEADs and added indices, and the bug in Git 2.5 through (but not including) 2.15

In Git, a *detached HEAD* just means that `HEAD` is not attached to a branch name.  Remember that the usual way to draw what's going on is to attach `HEAD` to some name:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

We can, instead, make Git point `HEAD` *directly to a commit*, without going through a branch name:

```
...--F--G   <-- HEAD
         \
          H   <-- master
```

When in this mode, if we make a *new* commit, Git writes the new commit's hash ID into `HEAD` itself, rather than the name that `HEAD` is not attached-to:

```
...--F--G--I   <-- HEAD
         \
          H   <-- master
```

An added work-tree can *always* be in detached HEAD mode, but there's a terrible bug in Git versions 2.5, where `git worktree` was first introduced, that's not fixed until Git version 2.15.

Specifically, each added work-tree has *its own* `HEAD` and its own private index file.  This is necessary due to the way the rest of Git works: `HEAD` records information about *this* work-tree, and the index is the index for *this* work-tree, so they are all one big group item.  Unfortunately, Git's *garbage collector*, `git gc`, was not properly taught to respect added work-trees.

The garbage collector's job is to find *unreferenced* (unused / unneeded) Git objects—blobs, trees, commits, and annotated tags that look like leftover junk in a repository.  Git uses this so that Git commands can, whenever they want, create these various internal objects without worrying about whether they're *really* necessary, and without having to take any special action to handle being interrupted (by, e.g., <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or a network session disconnection).  Other normal everyday Git actions, including `git rebase`, can generate this kind of junk.  That's all perfectly fine and normal, because the janitor, `git gc`, cleans it up regularly.

But any *new* commits you make with a detached HEAD have only `HEAD` itself referring to them.  In the *main* work-tree, this is not a problem: the `gc` janitor checks the `HEAD` file, sees the reference, and knows not to delete these commits.  But `git gc` doesn't check the *added, extra* HEADs.  So if you have an added work-tree with a detached HEAD, that detached HEAD's objects may vanish.  Similar rules apply to blob objects, and if a blob object stored in an added work-tree's index is referenced *only* from that index, `git gc` may remove the underlying blob object.

There's a secondary protection: `git gc` by default will not prune any object younger than 14 days old.  This gives all Git commands 14 days to get their work done, before the janitor comes by and throws their in-progress objects into the rubbish bin behind the office.  So this all works fine in the main work-tree, and works fine in added work-trees in Git 2.15 and later.  But for intermediate Git versions, `git gc` may come by, see a 14-or-more day old commit, tree, or blob that *shouldn't* be thrown out because of an added work-tree, and yet not realize that and throw it out.

This bug does not strike if you don't have a detached HEAD and are careful to add-and-commit within 14 days.  It also does not strike if you disable garbage collection, but that's not generally a great idea: Git depends on `gc` to clean up and maintain good performance.  And, of course, it was fixed in Git 2.15, so if you have that or later, you're fine.  It only affects added work-trees, so use caution between 2.5 and 2.15.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation- cleared my concepts for the first time. "This expectation is not supported by Git"- answers my question although it wasn't the answer I was hoping for. git worktree is not an useful option in my case because the imports resolve to paths of master worktree which will cause build issues so it seems having different repositories is the way to go. Git however should allow such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same question.  Just in case anyone here shares my confusion, I didn't realise that making a commit on the feature branch solves this problem!

Once you make the commit on one of the feature branches, the staged changes are removed from the other feature branch. Say, for example you add three lines of code in Branch 1.  If you checkout Branch 2, you will see these three lines.  BUT, if you first git add and git commit on Branch 1, then when you checkout Branch 2 you will not see these changes.

Hope this helps somebody.