# Git diff command documentation

Tags: git, git-diff

I am having trouble understanding the explanation of `git diff` command given in the book linked at the git website.

According to the [Pro Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), it says

> That command( `git diff`) compares what is in your working directory with what is in your staging area.

.

From my working with git it seems as though `git diff` compares your working directory with your **repository**.
I have a file that has been committed to the repo. I now modify this file. Without staging it, running git status shows me the file under *Changes not staged for commit* . Now if I run `git diff` I get the difference in code between what was in the repo and what is in the working directory. Shouldn't I get no output, as the modified file was not even staged?

Is there something wrong with my understanding in what the author was trying to convey?

Comment: The book author is correct, without additional parameters, `git diff` compares your working directory with your staging area. This means that if you make some changes, add those (so they are now in the staging area), then you make further changes and then you execute `git diff`, you will get back a diff between the two sets of changes.

Comment: in short, diff compares your change to staging area, be it remote repository (if changes are commited), local files (post-pre change), ets. This may help you: https://veerasundar.com/blog/2011/06/git-tutorial-comparing-files-with-diff/ as well as https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Comment: @RahulKumar The index is not empty before you run `git add`. It's filled with encrypted contents equivalent to the commit you have checked out.

Comment: @ElpieKay I understand now, thank you.

Comment: FYI, this "git diff" graph is helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587846/how-do-i-show-the-changes-which-have-been-staged/1587952#1587952

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `git diff` View difference between Stage and Working Directory
- `git diff --staged` View difference between HEAD and Stage
- `git diff HEAD` View difference between HEAD and Working Directory

Here `Stage` is the changes you have marked to include in the next commit.

`Working Directory` is the current directory you are working on and making changes.

`HEAD` is a reference to the last commit in the currently checked-out branch.

Try this once which might help you to clear up things:

Suppose I have a file `test.txt` and I have content `Hello` in the file which is currently in my repository. Now I change the file and add `World` and do `git status`:

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   test.txt
```

And when I check `git diff` it will show something like this:

```
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Hello
+Hello World
```

Now if I stage this file and check `git status`:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   test.txt
```

Now I observe I forgot to add exclamation mark to the text so I add that and check `git status` again:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   test.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   test.txt
```

So you can see that we have the same file in staged and unstaged area both. And when I check `git diff` it shows me this:

```
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Hello World
+Hello World!
```

We have changed `Hello World` which is in staged area right now to `Hello World!`, so it compared to the staged area. And now if I check `git diff --staged`:

```
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Hello
+Hello World
```

This compares the `staged` changes to the `HEAD` (the last commit). As I have not staged the `!` change it is not showing it here. And finally when I will do `git diff HEAD` it will show this:

```
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Hello
+Hello World!
```

The changes between `HEAD` (the last commit) and your `Working Directory`. As the `HEAD` has only `Hello` in the file and in your `Working Directory` you have changed it to `Hello World!` (it doesn't matters that you have not staged the `!` change, it will just look the file for changes whether they are staged or unstaged).

Hope this helps.