# Access the list of the staged files in a precommit hook

Tags: bash, git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I have a precommit hook that bumps up the software version on commits. However, I'd like to skip this functionality when only, say, `CHANGELOG.md` is updated. I tried:

```sh
diffs="$(git diff --name-only)"
if [[ $diffs == "CHANGELOG.md" ]]
then
    # echo 'no bump'
else
    # echo 'bump'
    # code that bumps the version
fi
```

But upon some inspection, the `diffs` variable is in fact blank even when `CHANGELOG.md` is staged. So it always evaluates the `else` statement. I was wondering if the diff is somehow accessible within a hook.

Comment: A staged file won’t show up in the diff without the “cache” flag. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1587846/4722345

Answer (score 0):

@JBallin's comment solves my issue. `--cached` or `--staged` should be used, so the code has to change to:

```sh
diffs="$(git diff --name-only --cached)"
if [[ $diffs == "CHANGELOG.md" ]]
then
    # echo 'no bump'
else
    # echo 'bump'
    # code that bumps the version
fi
```